# A problem with Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args) parameter count

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, invoke

I got an exeption like

> System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)

But System.Windows.Forms.Control contains only Invoke(Delegate method, **params** Object[] args) method but not Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args). And I use it like

> Invoke(new SetXDelegate(SetX), value1,
>   value2)

Is it the reason of my problem and I must use

> Invoke(new SetXDelegate(SetX), new
>   object[] {value1, value2})?

**UPDATE**

Please recommend if it better to use something like

> Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
>   SetX(value1, value2); })

to avoid this kind of problems.

Thanks.

Comment: What does SetXDelegate look like?

Comment: If SetX is an instance method, then the first object in the array should be the 'this' for the call, I think. If it takes 2 parameters, then you should pass 3 values in the args.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Yes you should. [It takes an array of objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb.aspx)</s>

**Edit**

The problem could be that SetXDelegate doesn't take two parameters.

Comment: Yes, but it takes them as a parameter array, so the two calls should be equivalent. I think it's much more likely that the SetXDelegate doesn't take two parameters... but we can't tell that yet :(

Comment: The MSDN documentation clearly shows the signature with "params" - and the question mentioned it too.

Comment: This [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) shows the different ways you can pass `params` arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think it's complaining that you're passing the wrong number of parameters for SetX to use. What parameters does SetX take?